# Haskell: read a file by line

Tags: haskell, file-io, input, functional-programming

I recently did the [Waterloo CCC](http://cemc.math.uwaterloo.ca/contests/computing.html) and I feel that Haskell is the perfect language for answering these types of questions. I am still learning it. I am struggling a bit with the input, though.

Here's what I'm using:

```
import IO
import System.Environment
import System.FilePath

…

main = do
    name <- getProgName
    args <- getArgs
    input <- readFile $
        if not (null args)
            then head args
            else dropExtension name ++ ".in"
    let (k:code:_) = lines input
    putStrLn $ decode (read k) code
```

As you can see, I'm reading from the command-line given file path or from `j1.in` for example, if this program is called `j1.hs` and compiled to `j1`.

I am only interested in the first two lines of the file, so I have used pattern matching to get those lines and bind them to `k` and `code`, in this example. And I then read `k` as an integer and pass it and the code string to my `decode` function, which I output.

I'm wondering if `readFile` is loading the entire file into memory, which would be bad. But then I started thinking, maybe since Haskell is lazy, it only ever reads the first two lines because that's all it's asked for later on. Am I right?

Also, if there is anything with that code sample that could be better or more idiomatic, please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documentation for `readFile`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=readFile) says:

> The `readFile` function reads a file and returns the contents of the file as a string. The file is read lazily, on demand, as with `getContents`.

So yes, it will only necessarily read the first two lines of the file (buffering means it will probably read more behind the scenes). But this is a property of `readFile` specifically, not of all Haskell I/O functions in general.

Lazy I/O is a bad idea for I/O-heavy programs (e.g. webservers) but it works nicely for simple programs that don't do much I/O.

Comment: In a tutorial `hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering` I saw used for stdin because input would only be entered one line at a time; would there be an equivalent for file input? If there is would it make sense to use it or would that be considered a premature optimization?

Comment: I disagree with your point that essentially lazy I/O is only useful when it's trivial. An example of a very useful feature of lazy I/O - in I/O-heavy settings - is that by default the data handling is inplace, meaning very efficient for large volumes of data.

Comment: @amindfv : He doesn't say that lazy I/O is _useless_ for big programs, he say that it's _bad_. What he means is that lazy IO often leads to resource leaks (here the file is never closed since it isn't read to its end) which are hard to correct in big and complex programs. More principled solutions to streaming are to be preferred (such as Iteratee or the more recent Conduit) because they gives you better control.

Comment: @amindfv Sorry, I worded that badly. I mean to say that lazy I/O is bad when you're continually opening (and only implicitly closing) numerous files/sockets/whatever. It does work well when the set of open file handles is fixed --- when the program doesn't do much I/O in the sense of not reading from or writing to too many disparate files.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, `readFile` is lazy. If you want to be explicit about it, you could use:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.IO

readLines n f = withFile f ReadMode $ replicateM n . hGetLine

-- in main
    (k:code:_) <- readLines 2 filename
```

This will ensure the file is closed as soon as possible.

But the way you've done it is fine.

Answer (score 3):

`readFile` reads the file lazily, so it won't read the entire file into memory unless you use the entire file. It will not usually read exactly the first two lines, since it reads in blocks, but it will only read as many blocks as needed to find the second newline.

Answer (score 3):

I/O in Haskell isn't usually lazy. However, the `readFile` function specifically *is* lazy.

Others have said the same thing. What I haven't seen anybody point out yet is that the file you've opened won't get closed until either the program ends or the garbage collector runs. That just means that the OS file handle might be kept open longer than necessary. In your program that's probably no big deal. But in a more complicated project, it could be.